# How to integrate StropheJs with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, strophe

Approaches that I have tried:

**Approach 1**:

1. Downloaded the `strophejs-1.3.4.zip` from http://strophe.im/strophejs/
2. Placed the unzipped folder i.e., `strophejs-1.3.4` in `src/assets` folder in my angular8 project.
3. In my `index.html` file have included

```
<!--// Strophe.js-->
  <script src='assets/strophejs-1.3.4/src/strophe.js'></script>
```

4. I installed @types/strophe using the command : `npm install --save-dev @types/strophe`
5. Then in my component.ts file
   declare let Strophe: any;

By following these steps the compilation is sucessful, however on running, I am getting run time reference error: `Reference Error: Strophe is not defined`

Below is my component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare let Strophe: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-oauth',
  templateUrl: './oauth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./oauth.component.scss']
})
export class OauthComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/bosh');
    // connection.rawInput = rawInput;
    // connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;

    connection.connect('user@localhost', 'password', this.onConnect);
  }

  onConnect(status) {
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
      console.log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
      console.log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
      console.log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
      console.log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
      console.log('Strophe is connected.');
    }
  }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

1. Installed npm pkg strophejs (I was reluctant on using it, as it mentions it is depricated)
   using the command `npm i strophe` in https://www.npmjs.com/package/strophe
2. Then in my component.ts file I am unable to import it. :(

> P.S There is an error(`Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations.`) shown in index.d.ts file of @types/strophe:

```
declare module "Strophe" {
   export = Strophe;
   ^^^^^^
 }
```

To Solve this issue I've referred the following:

1. [Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186841/exports-and-export-assignments-are-not-permitted-in-module-augmentations) - I didn't understand how I can implement this in my scenario
2. [Typescript error "An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements." while extending typescript definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708410/typescript-error-an-export-assignment-cannot-be-used-in-a-module-with-other-exp) - Tried this but didn't work
3. Tried the fix given in this https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/577, but this too didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Strophe npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/strophe is deprecated, and is thus not recommended to use it. I figured out how to use the downloaded file from http://strophe.im/strophejs/

Steps are as follows:

1. Navigate to the downloaded folder.
2. Then in it run npm install
    This creates a dist folder in which two files and a folder is created.
3. Copy the `Strophe.umd.min.js` file from the `/dist/Strophe.umd.js` folder and paste it in the /assets folder of your angular project.
4. Add the path of this file in `angular.json` file.

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/strophe.umd.min.js"
            ]
```

under the path mentioned by @canbax in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use npm package you should add to `angular.json` `projects>your-project-name>architect>build>options>scripts` like below. In the JSON file, it is a bit deep.

`"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",`

for ordinary JS library like jquery you can import it inside a TS file like

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Using together with types and typing support might be complicated.

Comment: Thank you, I included it in scripts and it worked. However, my concern is npm package is deprecated, can't I use the js library downloaded from Strophejs website - http://strophe.im/strophejs/

Comment: it seems like there is a strophe.js package in npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/strophe.js. This package https://www.npmjs.com/package/strophe also suggesting to use it.

Comment: @SHRUTHIBHARADWAJ of course you can use the downloaded js file. Simply put the downloaded file in your workspace and reference that file in your angular.json script section as described in the post. So instead of `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js` it could be `myfolder/downloadedfile.js`